# Send schedule message to telegram channel by bot telegram API nodejs

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

In order to send a regular message I use -

```js
const uri = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendMessage?chat_id=${channelId}&text=${text}`;

await fetch(uri);
```

But how to send a schedule message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bots can't schedule messages, there is corresponding error in docs: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage (see SCHEDULE_BOT_NOT_ALLOWED)

so only option is to plan sending with any scheduling tool on your side

Comment: Is there any way to automate scheduling messages without a bot?

Comment: @Gustavo You could create a user bot using MTProto protocol